# Access to Azure Data Lake Container by using a link

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Is it possible to share the contents of a container from azure data lake?
The goal is for anyone with the link to be able to download the files that are there.
Person who click the link should see folders and files which are there and has ability to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Allow Blob public access setting and change access level of container to Container. You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#about-anonymous-public-read-access). Then you can use this URL to list blobs in container:`https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list`. It will return xml file, you can copy the URL of blob and paste it in your browser to download it.

**Update:**
Yes, it's possible to use SAS key to do this while keeping your container is private.

You can generate SAS with list permission. And Use this URL to get blob list.

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?mySAStoken&restype=container&comp=list
```

And you can download file with this：

```
 https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfile?mySAStoken
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is it possible by using SAS key? I would like to avoid make container public.

Comment: @inspiredd updated my answer. You can have a try.